# Looping an array within an array php

Tags: php, arrays, json, foreach

Hi there i need some help to loop an array of items.
The part that I have repeated needs to be looped in order to get multiple items from the database. At this stage I am only to invoice one item where as users generally purchase a few so i need to run a foreach statement I think. Please excuse my ignorance and lack of understanding, I have tried a series of things but they do not seem to work

```
$json1 = array(
    'Date' => $currentDate->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s'),
    'Customer' => array(
        'DisplayID' => $phone
    ),
    'CustomerPurchaseOrderNumber' => $ordID,
    'Freight' => '0',
    'BalanceDueAmount' => '0.0',
    'Status' => 'Closed',
    'Lines' => /*$orderDetails,*/ array(

        array(
            'ShipQuantity' => $ShowDetails['quantity'],
            'UnitPrice' => $ShowDetails['unit_price'],
            'Total' => $ShowDetails['total_price'],
            'Item' => array(
                'UID' => $productUID,//itemuid(609400gmkit)
            ),
            'Description' => $productTitle. ' ' .$sizeTitle. ' ' 
.$colorTitle,
            'TaxCode' => array(
                'UID' => '7d1f2e99-ffe0-4463-9c29-
61d078b392d3'//taxcodeuid(GST)
            )

        )

    ),
    'Freight' => $shippingprice,//if dg then $10 otherwise $0 unless below 
$100
    'ShippingMethod' => $ShippingMethod,// if dg the 'MyFreight' otherwise 
'transdirect'
);
```

The portion that i need to loop is as follows :

```
 array( 
            'ShipQuantity' => $ShowDetails['quantity'],
            'UnitPrice' => $ShowDetails['unit_price'],
            'Total' => $ShowDetails['total_price'],
            'Item' => array(
                'UID' => '27d56af8-d3d6-4f0a-b71b-
4586fffbd63a'//itemuid(609400gmkit)
            ),
            'Description' => $productTitle. ' ' .$sizeTitle. ' ' 
.$colorTitle,
            'TaxCode' => array(
                'UID' => '7d1f2e99-ffe0-4463-9c29-
61d078b392d3'//taxcodeuid(GST)
            )

        )*/
```

Comment: can you be specific about which array you want to loop and what you want to do while looping? Please provide the array and mention what you want to do. Simple.

Comment: Hi there, thank you for your prompt reply. I'm trying to loop the following array which is then sent to an api (myob). (its the greyed bit of code above i need to do a foreach segment somehow or anyother that will loop the information gathered from the database

Comment: array(   
            'ShipQuantity' => $ShowDetails['quantity'],
            'UnitPrice' => $ShowDetails['unit_price'],
            'Total' => $ShowDetails['total_price'],
            'Item' => array(
                'UID' => '27d56af8-d3d6-4f0a-b71b-
4586fffbd63a'//itemuid(609400gmkit)
            ),
            'Description' => $productTitle. ' ' .$sizeTitle. ' ' 
.$colorTitle,
            'TaxCode' => array(
                'UID' => '7d1f2e99-ffe0-4463-9c29-
61d078b392d3'//taxcodeuid(GST)
            )

        ) $invoice = $accountRight->PostSaleInvoiceItem($json1);

Comment: It's really difficult to understand you, but if you just need something like:
foreach ($json1['Lines'] as $lineKey => $line){
  foreach ($line as $featKey => $feat) {
    print_r($featKey);
    echo(' = ');
    print_r($feat);
    echo("\n");
  }
}

then read it:
http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: Hi Dima, sorry i tried to explain as best as possible. essentially i just need to loop the segment that starts with shipping quantity but the stuff before that array and after is constant. I didn't know how to leave them all there and just get that part repeating. Thanks